iCloud drive errors on one Mac account
I've been having problems trying to use iCloud Drive on my Mac.  If I try to copy or move a file into iCloud Drive using Finder, I get an error -36.  If I try to open a PDF that is already in iCloud Drive using Preview, I get an error message saying "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." Numbers files give the same message.  On the other hand, I can view the contents of text or PDF files in iCloud Drive using Quick Look, and I can copy a file into it using the ditto command in Terminal, and the file does get uploaded to the cloud.
After looking at some previous similar discussions, I tried turning off iCloud Drive syncing and turning it back on, but that didn't help.
I can access iCloud using the web interface, but I'd rather not.
I created another account on my Mac, and set it to use iCloud with the same Apple ID, and it works there fine.  So whatever is messed up must be confined to my account.  But where?  I tried nuking various cache and preference files with "cloud" in their names, but no luck.
I'm using Ventura 13.6.9.
Same errors when booted in Safe Boot mode, same errors when back in normal mode.
I tried completely signing my Mac out of iCloud and signing back in.  The errors persist.
The message about a "helper application" inspired me to look at Activity Monitor for related processes.  I see that there is a process named com.apple.iCloudHelper belonging to the user account where iCloud Drive works, but no such process for the problematic account.
Running Console with com.apple.clouddocs in the search box for message text while triggering a -36 error produces:
default 14:43:55.792993-0700    runningboardd   Launch request for xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)> is using uid 501 (divined from auid 501 euid 501)
default 14:43:55.793081-0700    runningboardd   Executing launch request for xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)> (Launching extension com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider(D8EE5FE4-6ECB-4E19-81D2-2508981E7155) for host 7753)
default 14:43:55.793117-0700    runningboardd   Checking PreventLaunch: global:0 exPath:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider.appex/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider predicates:(null) allow:(null)
default 14:43:55.793165-0700    runningboardd   Creating and launching job for: xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>
default 14:43:55.793340-0700    runningboardd   '(null)' Submitting extension overlay (context <RBSLaunchContext: 0x7ff740058090>):
<dictionary: 0x7ff74003e9f0> { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    (trimmed for size)
default 14:43:55.805349-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Memory Limits: active 0 inactive 0
 <private>
default 14:43:55.805392-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] This process will not be managed.
default 14:43:55.805418-0700    runningboardd   Now tracking process: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]
default 14:43:55.805758-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] reported to RB as running
default 14:43:55.807219-0700    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "com.apple.extension.session" ID:178-7753-5720 target:7964 attributes:[
    <RBSLegacyAttribute| requestedReason:ViewService reason:ViewService flags:( AllowIdleSleep PreventTaskSuspend PreventTaskThrottleDown )>,
    <RBSAcquisitionCompletionAttribute| policy:AfterValidation>
    ]>
default 14:43:55.807317-0700    runningboardd   Assertion 178-7753-5720 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]) will be created as active
default 14:43:55.808026-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.808068-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 14:43:55.808104-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring role changes because this process is not role managed
default 14:43:55.808136-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 14:43:55.808202-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring memory limit update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.810547-0700    fileproviderd   Hit the server for a process handle 7c6772900001f1c that resolved to: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]
default 14:43:55.814753-0700    secinitd    com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider[7964]: root path for bundle "<private>" of main executable "<private>"
default 14:43:55.823057-0700    secinitd    AppSandboxUtilRealPathForUTF8StringPath(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider.appex)
default 14:43:55.828864-0700    secinitd    AppSandboxUtilRealPathForUTF8StringPath(/Volumes/Work/Users/jwwalker/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider/Data)
default 14:43:55.830346-0700    secinitd    com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider[7964]: AppSandbox request successful
default 14:43:55.834620-0700    containermanagerd   Using client sandbox path [<~~~>]; metadata = <<~~~>(2);<501/20/~~/0/1001>;uC761F768-E1A0-47EE-B476-7EC14BBB197D;pcom.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider;dp-1;uma(null);L0>
default 14:43:55.847044-0700    runningboardd   Setting client for [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] as ready
default 14:43:55.847537-0700    com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider Identity resolved as xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>
default 14:43:55.854887-0700    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 178-7753-5720 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]) from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753]
default 14:43:55.855267-0700    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "com.apple.extension.session" ID:178-7753-5721 target:7964 attributes:[
    <RBSLegacyAttribute| requestedReason:ViewService reason:ViewService flags:( AllowIdleSleep PreventTaskSuspend PreventTaskThrottleDown WantsForegroundResourcePriority )>,
    <RBSAcquisitionCompletionAttribute| policy:AfterValidation>
    ]>
default 14:43:55.855349-0700    runningboardd   Assertion 178-7753-5721 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]) will be created as active
default 14:43:55.855801-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.855842-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 14:43:55.855866-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring role changes because this process is not role managed
default 14:43:55.855889-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 14:43:55.855930-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] Ignoring memory limit update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.870681-0700    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 178-7753-5721 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]) from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753]
default 14:43:55.870774-0700    runningboardd   XPC connection invalidated: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]
default 14:43:55.871601-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964] termination reported by launchd (0, 0, 256)
default 14:43:55.871673-0700    runningboardd   Removing process: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]
default 14:43:55.871850-0700    runningboardd   Removing assertions for terminated process: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964]
default 14:43:55.871928-0700    runningboardd   Removed last relative-start-date-defining assertion for process xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>
default 14:43:55.895165-0700    runningboardd   Launch request for xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)> is using uid 501 (divined from auid 501 euid 501)
default 14:43:55.895240-0700    runningboardd   Executing launch request for xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)> (Launching extension com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider(D8EE5FE4-6ECB-4E19-81D2-2508981E7155) for host 7753)
default 14:43:55.895270-0700    runningboardd   Checking PreventLaunch: global:0 exPath:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider.appex/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider predicates:(null) allow:(null)
default 14:43:55.895384-0700    runningboardd   Creating and launching job for: xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>
default 14:43:55.895659-0700    runningboardd   '(null)' Submitting extension overlay (context <RBSLaunchContext: 0x7ff73843e1e0>):
<dictionary: 0x7ff73f70a890> { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    (trimmed for size)
default 14:43:55.908735-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Memory Limits: active 0 inactive 0
 <private>
default 14:43:55.908818-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] This process will not be managed.
default 14:43:55.908883-0700    runningboardd   Now tracking process: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]
default 14:43:55.909249-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] reported to RB as running
default 14:43:55.910732-0700    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "com.apple.extension.session" ID:178-7753-5723 target:7965 attributes:[
    <RBSLegacyAttribute| requestedReason:ViewService reason:ViewService flags:( AllowIdleSleep PreventTaskSuspend PreventTaskThrottleDown )>,
    <RBSAcquisitionCompletionAttribute| policy:AfterValidation>
    ]>
default 14:43:55.910840-0700    runningboardd   Assertion 178-7753-5723 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]) will be created as active
default 14:43:55.911410-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.911448-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 14:43:55.911603-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring role changes because this process is not role managed
default 14:43:55.911796-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 14:43:55.912101-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring memory limit update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.915251-0700    fileproviderd   Hit the server for a process handle 5e7828500001f1d that resolved to: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]
default 14:43:55.917201-0700    secinitd    com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider[7965]: root path for bundle "<private>" of main executable "<private>"
default 14:43:55.924221-0700    secinitd    AppSandboxUtilRealPathForUTF8StringPath(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider.appex)
default 14:43:55.928647-0700    secinitd    AppSandboxUtilRealPathForUTF8StringPath(/Volumes/Work/Users/jwwalker/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider/Data)
default 14:43:55.930151-0700    secinitd    com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider[7965]: AppSandbox request successful
default 14:43:55.934633-0700    containermanagerd   Using client sandbox path [<~~~>]; metadata = <<~~~>(2);<501/20/~~/0/1001>;uC761F768-E1A0-47EE-B476-7EC14BBB197D;pcom.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider;dp-1;uma(null);L0>
default 14:43:55.948535-0700    runningboardd   Setting client for [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] as ready
default 14:43:55.949438-0700    com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider Identity resolved as xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>
error   14:43:55.956657-0700    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 178-7753-5720 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964])
error   14:43:55.956712-0700    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 178-7753-5721 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7964])
default 14:43:55.960716-0700    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 178-7753-5723 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]) from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753]
default 14:43:55.961103-0700    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "com.apple.extension.session" ID:178-7753-5724 target:7965 attributes:[
    <RBSLegacyAttribute| requestedReason:ViewService reason:ViewService flags:( AllowIdleSleep PreventTaskSuspend PreventTaskThrottleDown WantsForegroundResourcePriority )>,
    <RBSAcquisitionCompletionAttribute| policy:AfterValidation>
    ]>
default 14:43:55.961190-0700    runningboardd   Assertion 178-7753-5724 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]) will be created as active
default 14:43:55.961682-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.961729-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 14:43:55.961751-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring role changes because this process is not role managed
default 14:43:55.961770-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 14:43:55.961807-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] Ignoring memory limit update because this process is not memory-managed
default 14:43:55.983042-0700    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 178-7753-5724 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]) from originator [osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753]
default 14:43:55.983144-0700    runningboardd   XPC connection invalidated: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]
default 14:43:55.984157-0700    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965] termination reported by launchd (0, 0, 256)
default 14:43:55.984211-0700    runningboardd   Removing process: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]
default 14:43:55.984417-0700    runningboardd   Removing assertions for terminated process: [xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965]
default 14:43:55.984483-0700    runningboardd   Removed last relative-start-date-defining assertion for process xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>
error   14:43:56.131131-0700    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 178-7753-5724 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965])
error   14:43:56.131270-0700    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 178-7753-5723 (target:[xpcservice<com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider([osservice<com.apple.FileProvider(501)>:7753])(501)>:7965])


Please start up in safe mode and test, then reboot as usual and test again. Update your question with the results.

Please sign out of iCloud completely, then sign back in. Make sure you know the password before doing this. If prompted to save or delete data in iCloud, choose to save.

This is going to be tricky because I don't have access to a Ventura system, and some things may have changed. There may a folder in your home folder with the relative path Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider . If there is, disable iCloud Drive sync again, then move that folder to the Trash, but don't empty yet. Re-enable syncing and test.

@LincD.  In ~/Library/Containers, I found a folder whose name was displayed by Finder as just iCloudDrive, but Get Info showed that the actual name was com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider.  I turned off iCloud Drive, trashed the folder, and turned iCloud Drive on again.  No change to the errors.

You could try the solution of a Ventura user who apparently had the same problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254860480 . I can't verify the solution because it's not applicable to Sonoma.

Thanks, but deleting the ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents folder did not work for me.

Please launch the built-in Console application and enter the following into the search box: com.apple.clouddocs. Then take one of the actions that causes an error. Update your question with the log messages that appear -- no more than about 50 lines.

You seem to have moved your home folder to another volume named "Work". Is that correct? Did you also do that with the other account, in which the error doesn't occur? Did iCloud Drive ever work after the move?

@LincD. Yes, I have moved my home folder to a volume named "Work".  I have been using that setup for years (which is why I forgot to mention it), and iCloud drive used to work.  I tried creating another admin account with a home folder on "Work", linked to the same Apple ID, and iCloud Drive works there.

With iCloud Drive sync disabled, please move this folder from your home folder to the Trash: Library/Application Support/CloudDocs . Any change?

There was no change.

The key piece of information here is the fact that a helper process, com.apple.iCloudHelper, is not running in the problem account. I'm stymied by the fact that this process no longer exists in Sonoma, which is what I have. I'd like to know what files in the user's home folder are opened by that process. To that end, please log in to the other account, launch Activity Monitor, and open the inspector for that process. What files are listed as open? I'm only interested in user files (under /Users).

See https://eclecticlight.co/2023/07/24/how-to-fix-problems-with-icloud-and-icloud-drive/

I seem to have solved my problem, albeit in an unsatisfying way.  Having gotten tired of trashing a file here and there, I decided to move aside whole subfolders of ~/Library, while not logged into the problematic account:
~/Library/Application Support
~/Library/Containers
~/Library/Group Containers

Then when I logged in, the problem still existed. So I logged out and used another admin account to move some more folders aside:
~/Library/com.apple.icloud/searchpartyd
~/Library/Caches
~/Library/Daemon Containers
~/Library/Mobile Documents
~/Library/Preferences

At that point, the problem was gone!  Then I started moving these folders back into place one at a time, logging in to test each time.  And after I had moved all 8 folders back into place, iCloud Drive was still working.  Cue "Twilight Zone" theme.

The problem has cropped up more than once again, and I've tried moving aside different folders. My current minimal set:
~/Library/Mobile Documents
~/Library/Application Support


Thanks for the update. You should post that solution as an answer and accept it.

Them being removed likely causes icloud to rebuild its database or similar stuff
